# Objective-C class representing JSON

Tags: objective-c, restkit

I am new to RestKit and an Objective-C newbie. The JSON that I would like to turn into Objective-C objects has the following format.

```
{
   "id":1,
   "ron95":700.0,
   "ron92":700.0,
   "dieselNormal":700.0,
   "dieselSpecial":700.0,
   "postDate":1435465383000
}
```

In Java, the JSON would be represented like this:

```
public class Price {

    private Long id;
    private Double ron95;
    private Double ron92;
    private Double dieselNormal;
    private Double dieselSpecial;
    private java.util.Date postDate;

    ...
}
```

What would the mapping Objective-C class be like and how would you do the mapping using RestKit?

**Edit:** This is what I think my Objective-C representation should look like. Correct me if I am wrong.

**Price.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Price : NSObject {
    NSInteger id;
    double ron95;
    double ron92;
    double dieselNormal;
    double dieselSpecial;
    NSDate *postDate;
}

@property (nonatomic) NSInteger id;
@property (nonatomic) double ron95;
@property (nonatomic) double ron92;
@property (nonatomic) double dieselNormal;
@property (nonatomic) double dieselSpecial;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *postDate;

@end
```

**Price.m**

```
#import "Price.h"

@implementation Price

@synthesize id;
@synthesize ron95;
@synthesize ron92;
@synthesize dieselNormal;
@synthesize dieselSpecial;
@synthesize postDate;

@end
```

Comment: What you are asking is how to define your class' members, or how to convert the class to JSON?

Comment: You have written Objective-C code before, right? So then translating your class into Objective-C is more than trivial.

Comment: I guess I am going to use `long`, `float` and `NSDate` types, right?

Comment: Watch out for objective c's json parsing. Sometimes it's unstable wrt what type it thinks it's reading, so you'll want to cast/do type checking.

Comment: It looks like you are using an older style of Objective-C. You no longer need the portion inside the braces nor the `@synthensize` statements. The `@property` statements are sufficient. Other than that, your structure is essentially correct.

Comment: @EricS I learned Objective-C five years ago. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: You're better off using `NSNumber` rather than trying to go direct to primitive types. You don't really say enough about how you're going to store this data as you may be better served by core data and mogenerator...

Comment: @Wain. Thanks for pointing out. I have changed `double` to `NSNumber`. I am using CoreData to save the resultant objects to the database and I have created the `ManagedPrice` class to deal with ORM.

Answer (score 1):

I have been looking into this for a while. I decided to write my own solution. It is very simple and built upon existing Apple functionality. Just go to github and copy the source to your project. Have your Price class inherit from GSObject instead of NSObject.

Write a category for NSDate class with this class method:
+(id) initWithJsonValue:(NSString*)jsonValue
Here is where you would convert the date string 
"postDate":1435465383000
to an NSDate probably using a date formatter.

See here: https://github.com/gslinker/GSObject

And here: http://digerati-illuminatus.blogspot.com/2016/01/objective-c-and-json-convert-subclass.html

Here is a sample that I made, notice it has an NSDate object as well.

For your data model object have it inherit from GSObject instead of NSObject. Here is an example of ThingOne with inherits from GSObject:

```
ThingOne* object1 = [[ThingOne alloc] init];
object1.name = @"John Jones";


NSData* jsonData1 = [object1 toJsonDataWithOptions:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted];
NSString *jsonString1 = [object1 toJsonStringWithOptions:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted];

NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *dict1 =  [GSObject dictionaryWithValues:object1];

NSString *roundTripJson1 = [object1 toJsonStringWithOptions:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted];




//
//  ThingOne.h
//  JasonStuff
//
//  Created by Geoffrey Slinker on 12/28/15.
//  Copyright © 2015 Slinkworks LLC. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "GSObject.h"
#import "ThingTwo.h"

@interface ThingOne : GSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) ThingTwo *thingTwo;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *values;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary *dict;
@property int myInt;
@property float myFloat;
@property BOOL myBool;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber* someMoney;


@end

//
//  ThingOne.m
//  JasonStuff
//
//  Created by Geoffrey Slinker on 12/28/15.
//  Copyright © 2015 Slinkworks LLC. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ThingOne.h"

@implementation ThingOne

@synthesize name;
@synthesize thingTwo;
@synthesize values;
@synthesize dict;
@synthesize myInt;
@synthesize myFloat;
@synthesize myBool;
@synthesize someMoney;

- (instancetype)init
{
self = [super init];

thingTwo = [[ThingTwo alloc] init];

thingTwo.stuff = @"Thing Two Stuff";
thingTwo.someOtherStuff = @"Thing Two Other Stuff";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormater = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormater setDateFormat:@"yyyy-mm-dd"];
thingTwo.someDate =  [dateFormater dateFromString:@"1963-10-07"];

values = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Value1", @"Value2", @"Value3", nil];

dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"value1", @"key1", @"value2", @"key2", nil];

myInt = 5431;
myFloat = 123.456f;
myBool = YES;

someMoney = [NSNumber numberWithInt:503];

return self;
}

@end

//
//  ThingTwo.h
//  JasonStuff
//
//  Created by Geoffrey Slinker on 12/28/15.
//  Copyright © 2015 Slinkworks LLC. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "GSObject.h"

@interface ThingTwo : GSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *stuff;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *someOtherStuff;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *someDate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *nullString;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *nullDate;

@end

//
//  ThingTwo.m
//  JasonStuff
//
//  Created by Geoffrey Slinker on 12/28/15.
//  Copyright © 2015 Slinkworks LLC. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ThingTwo.h"

@implementation ThingTwo

@synthesize stuff;
@synthesize someOtherStuff;
@synthesize someDate;

- (instancetype)init
{
self = [super init];

someDate = [NSDate date];

return self;
}

@end
```

Here is an example of the JSON output:

```
{
  "values" : [
    "Value1",
    "Value2",
    "Value3"
  ],
  "myInt" : 5431,
  "myFloat" : 123.456,
  "myBool" : true,
  "someMoney" : "$503.00",
  "thingTwo" : {
    "stuff" : "Thing Two Stuff",
    "nullDate" : null,
    "someDate" : "1963-01-07 07:10:00 +0000",
    "nullString" : null,
    "someOtherStuff" : "Thing Two Other Stuff"
  },
  "name" : "John Jones",
  "dict" : {
    "key1" : "value1",
    "key2" : "value2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have a look at https://github.com/icanzilb/JSONModel, from cocoapods

all (de)serialization is handled automatically for you, even complex structures of array of custom objects.

Been using it, been loving it...